# Feign does not resolve name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, openfeign

I am trying t call another service using Spring Cloud's Open Feign but here is the response I keep getting:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1579015052962,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "auth-service: Name or service not known executing GET http://auth-service/api/v1/auth",
  "path": "/api/v1/event"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.eventmanager.events.client;

import com.eventmanager.events.client.mappings.Auth;
import com.eventmanager.events.config.CustomFeignClientConfig;
import com.eventmanager.events.responses.Response;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

@FeignClient(name = "auth-service", configuration = CustomFeignClientConfig.class)
public interface AuthClient {
  @GetMapping("/api/v1/auth")
  public Response<Auth> getLoggedUser(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization);
}
```

I configured Feign to use the OkHttp client and I'm not sure if it's responsible for the error:

```
package com.eventmanager.events.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient;

@Configuration
public class CustomFeignClientConfig {
  @Bean
  public OkHttpClient client() {
    return new OkHttpClient();
  }
}
```

Comment: have you added eureka.instance.hostname =<hostname> in properties file

Comment: Are you using a discovery client like eurkea or consul?

Comment: @spencergibb I am making use of Eureka

Comment: Do you have ribbon on the classpath? What version are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb. I do not have Ribbon on the classpath. I'm using the Finchley.SR1 version.

Comment: If you aren't using ribbon set the `url` property. Finchley is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Finchey.SR1, You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727544
There seems to be an issue with ContentPath in that cloud version.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'm a little late to the party. The following dependency can be added to your pom.xml file. If you you have `feign-okhttp` dependency then you should be having this dependency by default.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-alpha.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Now instead of importing `feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient;` import  `okhttp3.OkHttpClient`.

So your class should look like below.

```
package com.eventmanager.events.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

@Configuration
public class CustomFeignClientConfig {
  @Bean
  public OkHttpClient client() {
    return new OkHttpClient();
  }
}
```

Also consider adding the below entry in your `application.properties` file. This will stop Feign from using the default http client.

```
feign.httpclient.enabled=false
```

You may refer to this [post](https://blog.birost.com/a?ID=01050-b9ea9408-d2ac-40a3-ae88-9be8b87e1da8) for more information

Comment: I am getting `Exception feign.RetryableException: service-name: Name or service not known executing POST` error. Any fix for this?

Comment: Are you using 'eureka' and 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient' @ShashankShekher?

Answer (score 0):

May be because you have not specified base URL. for client & it is taking base URL as auth-service.

```
@FeignClient(name = "auth-service", configuration = CustomFeignClientConfig.class, url = "http://lcoalhost:8080")
public interface AuthClient {
  @GetMapping("/api/v1/auth")
  public Response<Auth> getLoggedUser(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization);
}
```

Comment: Is there need for a base url? The service name should be enough since that works locally.